# Avoid keycloak callback process every time when refreshing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, configuration, keycloak

I have used keycloak as a identity provider in my react application. I have installed keycloak react dependency in my react application using npm.

Below are the dependent keycloak react npm modules with version :

"@react-keycloak/web": "2.1.4",
"keycloak-js": "^11.0.2",

I have provided keycloak configurations as below :

```
const keycloak = new Keycloak({
  realm: "temp-local",
  url: " http://localhost:8090/auth/",
  clientId: "temp-local-client"
});
```

Everytime when I refresh the page it will refresh again (with callback url) with query parameters **state**, **session_state** and **code**.

For example :
When I go to the page : http://localhost:8080/test it will go there but again it will refresh the page with below url.

Sample url : http://localhost:8080/test#**state**=45ert45-edac92ddbf2a&**session_state**=45ga97bbfb4-f080cvb65e59b&**code**=1a1a-4e6e-3fg578-4fg10b-bbafg8-652fg6c44727a4

How to avoid that keycloak refresh? Can anyone have any idea on this?

Answer (score 3):

I've faced it as well and what helped me was to use the silent check SSO:

---

- Next to an `index.html` add a file called `silent-check-sso.html` with a following content:

```
<html><body><script>parent.postMessage(location.href, location.origin)</script></body></html>
```

- Update your `<ReactKeycloakProvider>` with `initOptions` like:

```
    <ReactKeycloakProvider
      authClient={keycloak}
      initOptions={{
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/silent-check-sso.html',
        pkceMethod: 'S256',
      }}
    >
    ...
    </ReactKeycloakProvider>
```

---

Unfortunately I'm not aware of the technical details of how it works (explaining comments are welcomed) but it helped me : ] Here is how it worked without silent check SSO on:

[image]

And this is with silent check SSO:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, for me i fixed like this:

in the main component:

```
const App = () => {
    //here i'm using redux, btw i'm initializing this auth component
    useEffect(() => auth.init(store.dispatch), [])
```

the auth component:

```
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';
const keycloak = Keycloak('/keycloak.json');
import axios from 'axios'
import { LocalStore } from '../utils/local_store.js'

const store_token = (token) => {
    axios.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    LocalStore.set('token', token);
}

const auth = {
    init(dispatch) {


        keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required', checkLoginIframe: false, }).then(() => {
            store_token(keycloak.token)
            dispatch(authenticateResponse(keycloak.token)).then(
                () => {
                   //auth logic
                }
            );

            //this is my fix
            setInterval(() => {
                keycloak.updateToken(70).then((refreshed) => {
                    if (refreshed) {
                        store_token(keycloak.token)
                        console.debug('Token refreshed');
                    } else {
                        console.warn('Token not refreshed');
                    }
                }).catch(() => {
                    console.error('Failed to refresh token');
                });
            }, 50000)

        }).catch(() => {
            console.error('Auth failed');
        });
    },
    keycloak() {
        return keycloak;
    }
}


export default auth;
```

Comment: I'll try that but what is LocalStore and ../utils/local_store.js flie ? is it localStorage ?

Comment: LocalStore is just a tool that wrap lockr, you can just use lockr for local store if you want to storre the token in local store

Comment: I have tried the solution you have suggested but for me it's going in infinite loop (it refreshing again and again).

Answer (score 0):

Check if other parts of the code are doing redirects in react-router:
I had the same problem, but in a large code base where other errors (because of lack of token) caused internal redirects to the login route